# Close other multitasking apps with our application with code - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, multitasking

I want to close other application running background with my app

how can i do it?

Comment: As a developer of one of those other applications, I'm glad you can't do this.  This disrupts the user experience by forcing them to relaunch every other application but yours.  If you can't play well within the memory provided for your application on the system, you need to spend some time tuning your own application before looking at how to terminate others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not possible

...unless your are programming in a jailbroken iPhone

Comment: Yes, there is an app called "Remove Background" but is for jailbreak. So there is a way to do it but I couldn't find it. I want just want to know how can we do it by code??

Answer (score 0):

You can request the user (who is in control of their device) to kill background apps manually and/or reboot their device.  Which is **not** a good user experience, even though I've seen this request on some game app support forums/FAQs.